# Image upload doesnt work

Tags: php, mysql, upload

I got this upload script but when I want to run it, the page returns blank. There is something wrong, but I cannot figure out where the error is and how to fix it. I would appreciate if someone helped me to make this script work ! **MANY thanks !**

```
<?php
    $allowedExts = array("jpg", "jpeg", "gif", "png");
    $extension = end(explode(".", $_FILES["file"]["name"]));
    if ((($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/gif")
    || ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/jpeg")
    || ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/png")
    || ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/pjpeg"))
    && ($_FILES["file"]["size"] < 20000)
    && in_array($extension, $allowedExts))
      {
      if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] > 0)
        {
        echo "Return Code: " . $_FILES["file"]["error"] . "<br>";
        }
      else
        {
        echo "Upload: " . $_FILES["file"]["name"] . "<br>";
        echo "Type: " . $_FILES["file"]["type"] . "<br>";
        echo "Size: " . ($_FILES["file"]["size"] / 1024) . " kB<br>";
        echo "Temp file: " . $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"] . "<br>";

        if (file_exists("upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]))
          {
          echo $_FILES["file"]["name"] . " already exists. ";
          }
        else
          {
          move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], "upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
            include 'db.php';
            mysql_query("INSERT INTO `members`(img) VALUES ('$_FILES["file"]["name"]')");
            include 'succes.php';
            }
        }
      }
    else
      {
      echo "Invalid file";
      }
    ?>
```

Comment: have you verified that your "upload/" folder exists with correct read/write permissions on said folder?

If the page returns white;then it is possible you have a fatal error inside your code. Turn on your error handling to E_ALL and post any error codes shown

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12859942/). They are no longer maintained and the [deprecation process](http://news.php.net/php.internals/53799) has begun on it. See the [**red box**](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo), or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](https://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers).

However, check that `upload/` folder has `read and write` permissions and use this working code:

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO `members`(img) VALUES ('" . $_FILES["file"]["name"] . "');");
```

See that using that code there's an SQL injection vulnerability, I suggest you to prepare queries via `PDO`.

If you have to update an existing record use:

```
mysql_query("UPDATE `members` SET img = '" . $_FILES["file"]["name"] . "' WHERE member_id = '" . $member_id . "';");
```

If you have to add new image to an existing member you could try:

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO `members` (img, member_id) VALUES ('" . $_FILES["file"]["name"] . "', '" . $member_id . "');");
```

Comment: Third, avoid SQL injection vulnerabilities.

Comment: +1 for your comment! Preparing query via `PDO` is very suggested and helps with that too!

Comment: @jan267 One more ! It worked but it made a new table, it has to insert into a excisted one, so i tried with Member ID, the upload succeeds but the database doesnt contain the name ! 

`$member_id = $_SESSION['SESS_MEMBER_ID'];
  mysql_query("INSERT INTO 'members' (img) where member_id = '$member_id' VALUES ('{$_FILES["file"]["name"]}')");`

Answer (score 2):

There was a error in this line

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO `members`(img) VALUES ('$_FILES["file"]["name"]')");
```

change that line to

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO `members`(img) VALUES ('{$_FILES["file"]["name"]}')");
```

**UPDATE:**

Error was `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '"', expecting T_STRING or T_VARIABLE or T_NUM_STRING on line 30`

**Note:** Don't use `mysql_*` function they will be deprecated soon. Instead use PDO or mysqli function. Before inserting data to database, alway validate the data and beware of SQL Injections.